# Select a specific duplicate entry

Tags: sql

I have a table set up similar to the following:

```
Userid | LastFirstMI |   Active
  1      Doe, Jane S     False <<<
  2      Doe, Jane S     True 
  3      Smith, John P   False 
  4      Lee, Bob R      False 
  5      Bob, Joe L      False <<< 
  6      Bob, Joe L      True
```

I'm wanting to only select the duplicate names with an Active value of False. I've indicated the rows with <<<. I've searched and found similar questions, but I can't seem to find one that shows how to select a specific duplicate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which db you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return duplicates where `Active = 'False'` when there is a corresponding `Active = 'True'` account.

```
select userid, LastFirstMI, Active 
from t
where t.Active = 'False'
  and exists (
    select 1
    from t as i
    where i.LastFirstMi = t.LastFirstMi
      and i.Active = 'True'
  )
```

---

This will return all duplicates where `Active = 'False'` even if there is not a corresponding `Active = 'True'` account.

```
select userid, LastFirstMI, Active 
from t
where t.Active = 'False'
  and exists (
    select 1
    from t as i
    where i.LastFirstMi = t.LastFirstMi
      and i.UserId <> t.UserId
  )
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.userid, t1.LastFirstMI, t1.Active from table t1,table t2
where t1.active='False' and t1.LastFirstMI=t2.LastFirstMI and t2.active='True'
```

Try the code above and please change `active=False` condition according to your db engine if needed.

Comment: the where condition must match the number of columns is subselect

Comment: Corrected, you can check.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column active is a string

This should work in mysql  and SQLServer

```
select * from my_table where 
Active  = 'False' and LastFirstMi in (
  select t.LastFirstMi from ( 
    select  LastFirstMI, count(*)
    from my_table 
    group LastFirstMI 
    having count(*)>1
  ) t 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number in most databases:

```
Select *
From (
  Select t.*
    ,row_number() over (partition by lastfirstMI order by Active) rn
  From your_table t
) t where rn = 1
```

Comment: That will return records with `Active = 'True'` when there is no duplicate.  `where rn = 1 and Active = 'false'` is one way to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

```
with x as (
select Userid, LastFirstMI,Active
       , row_number() over (partition by LastFirstMI order by Active desc) as row_number
from table
)

select * from x 
where Active = 'False'
      and row_number >= 2
```